# which network adapter is shared in ICS 2008

Tags: windows-server-2008

I have two ethernet adapters in my computer. I am trying to use ICS.
BUt i am confused to which network adapter i have to apply ICS

1)To which my main internet is comming or
2)To which i have joined cable to another computer

Secondly do i have to write any setting manually like gateway or ip range in that shared adapter in either server or client PC

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The one that connects to the Internet.  And no, you should not need to manually set any setting, the wizard takes care of all of that (the client will need to be using DHCP to get its IP settings).

More on ICS here:

- http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows-vista/Using-ICS-Internet-Connection-Sharing
- http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc770507(WS.10).aspx